# Cannot create file with Polish encoding

Tags: python

I am scraping data from a web-site and i have got a problem. I cannot create a file with data in polish encoding. I got a lot of unicode characters, but i do not want to have them instead of real characters. Could anyone help me? Thanks.

Here is some part of output content i get:

> le\u015bnych, hibiskusa lub brzoskwini  250 g cukru  5 g kwasku
>   cytrynowego  2 \u0142y\u017cki soku z cytryny

Here is the code creating the file:

```
with codecs.open('recipes.txt', 'w', 'cp1250') as w:
    w.write(string)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: do you use Python 2 ? On Python 3 you can use standard `open(.. encoding='cp1250')` but Python 2 didn't have option `encoding=` in standard `open()`.

Comment: your code works for me without errors on Python 2 and 3. You should add full error message in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Python 3 it gives always correct text

```
leśnych, hibiskusa lub brzoskwini 250 g cukru 5 g kwasku cytrynowego 2 łyżki soku z cytryny
```

So it seems you use Python 2 which always had problem with Polish coding.
(Polish is my native language).

Python 2 treats `\u015b` as normal string, not unicode char `ś`.

You have to `encode` and `decode` it again.

```
text = text.encode().decode('unicode_escape')
```

You should see correct text when you even use `print()`
(if only your system can works with `CP1250` and has font with Polish chars)

---

Minimal working code

```
import codecs

text  = 'le\u015bnych, hibiskusa lub brzoskwini 250 g cukru 5 g kwasku cytrynowego 2 \u0142y\u017cki soku z cytryny'

text = text.encode().decode('unicode_escape') 
#print(text)

with codecs.open('recipes.txt', 'w', 'cp1250') as w:
    w.write(text)
```

Comment: OK, thank you for the info. But i have found the solution before i saw your answer and forgot to delete question. Please, sorry for wasting your time. But if you want to know, i tried to add .prettify('iso-8859-1').decode('utf-8', errors='replace') to string and it worked. Again, sorry

Comment: You can add your solution as answer - it can be useful for other users.

Comment: BTW: if you use `.prettify()` then you work with `BeautifulSoup` and maybe all problem is in different place - ie. maybe `BeautifulSoup` has problem with encoding or page use different encoding then you expect. BTW: old Polish pages used `iso-8859-2`, not `iso-8859-1` but currently most pages use `utf-8`

Answer (score 0):

The solution i found for me useful is to add .prettify('iso-8859-1').decode('utf-8', errors='replace') to all the strings you need to add. But before, please, read @furas answer and some comments from him.